# Unable to pull AWS image for Python 2.7.12

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, build-server

My CloudFormation template contains the following resource definition:

```
MyBuildResource:
  Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
  Properties:
    Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-my-build-resource
    ServiceRole: !Ref MyServiceRole
    Artifacts:
      Type: CODEPIPELINE
    Source:
      Type: CODEPIPELINE
      BuildSpec: subtemplate.yaml
    Environment:
      ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
      Image: aws/codebuild/python:2.7.12
      Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
      EnvironmentVariables:
        - Name: FOO
          Value: 42
```

I get the error message "Unable to pull customer's container image. ErrorCode: 404, Reason: pull access denied for aws/codebuild/python, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'". This doesn't make sense to me as the images [appears to be available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html). Is something else wrong in the resource definition?

Answer (score 0):

I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/47465100 provides the correct answer. `MyServiceRole` needs to

```
Effect: Allow
Action:
  - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
  - ecr:BatchGetImage
  - ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
Resource: "*"
```

Previously, I only allowed those actions on my own repository, which would prevent me from getting the AWS images.

EDIT: I've updated as I confirm the problem and its resolution.